# Has anyone successfully used azure-storage for blob storage in a react native project?

Tags: react-native, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-storage

Based on this project or potentially another, has anyone used any JavaScript package for azure blob storage uploads?

I only post here as my research has returned little results, so I though a potential conversation into the lack of react native support from azure might uncover some workarounds.

I will continue to try the listed package and provide results if successful, so as always thanks for any response and direction as it's always greatly appreciated!

Edit:
This looks interesting, though I have not looked into it in great detail:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-blob-storage

Comment: Just for clarification: Have you referred to the suggestion mentioned in the below link: https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob#user-content-upload-example--dropbox-files-upload-api 
You can use the Azure Storage JavaScript Client Library to directly upload the photo from the client to Azure Storage: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/tree/master/browser.  See the sample here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/blob/master/browser/samples/sample-blob.html

Comment: @SumanthMarigowda-MSFT - Except your first suggestion, your all suggestions are for browser do you have any help for React Native mobile. 
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

In case someone is struggling to make it work with other solutions proposed here. Here is another one using `rn-fetch-blob`. This solution also allows saving a blob with custom name e.g., `customBlobName`

```
import RNFetchBlob from "rn-fetch-blob";

const sasContainerUri = "https://accountname.blob.core.windows.net";

const container = "minecontainer";

const sasToken =
  "sv=2019-02-02&ss=b&srt=sco&sp=rwdlac&se=2020-05-30T22:48:22Z&st=2020-05-25T14:48:22Z&spr=https&sig=otherpartofSAStoken"; // you may need to play with other html verbs in this string e.g., `sp`, `ss` e.t.c.

const localUri = Constants.platform.ios
      ? file.uri.replace("file://", "/")
      : file.uri;

const assetPath = `${sasContainerUri}/${container}/${customBlobName}`;

    try {
      await RNFetchBlob.fetch(
        "PUT",
        `${assetPath}?${sasToken}`,
        {
          "x-ms-blob-type": "BlockBlob",
          "content-type": "application/octet-stream",
          "x-ms-blob-content-type": file.type
        },
        RNFetchBlob.wrap(localUri)
      );
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Error at saving image into Azure Storage", e);
    }
```

Comment: I am receiving authentication error. Any advice? Server fail
ed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.

Comment: The answer is not complete and giving the error "Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature."

Answer (score 2):

Yes I have used.

```
 const localUri = __IS_IOS ? file.uri.replace('file://', '') : file.uri;
 const assetPath = `${_trimEnd(sasContainerUri, '/')}/${container}/${uploadPath}`;

  await RNFetchBlob.fetch('PUT', `${assetPath}?${sasToken}`, {
    'x-ms-blob-type': 'BlockBlob',
    'content-type': 'application/octet-stream',
    'x-ms-blob-content-type': file.type,
  }, RNFetchBlob.wrap(localUri));

return assetPath
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate a more detailed solution? I am getting "This request is not authorized to perform this operation." error.

Comment: I am getting error code 409 Operation is not allowed in the state of the entity. Any solution for this @Nikhil, Thanks in advance

Comment: I bit late, but I guess the last two comments are due to a misconfiguration on the SAS token in the Azure portal.
Go to the container > Settings > Shared Access Tokens > Create an Account Key with the right permissions. Then you will get the Blob SAS Token required.

Answer (score 2):

```
npm install react-native-azure-blob-storage --save
```

https://github.com/PosSoolutions/react-native-azure-blob-storage